# Multi thread reading from files

Tags: c, multithreading, output, malloc

I am currently trying to produce outputs with three separate programs (process1, 2, and 3) and a main program that I want to read from the files and append to a string. Currently in my functions all I do is 1. Open the file, 2. read the char, 3. append it to my char buffer, and 4. print out output. (The three processes have different time intervals at which it produces integers and characters).

```
//Function for process 1 (Every second)
void thread1_func(void) {
  char *c; //Have to use *c because second param of strcat is a char pointer
  while(1) {
    usleep(50000);
    //Reading from file
    output = fopen("output1.txt", "r");
    fscanf(output, "%c", &c); //Copy int to c
    strcat(o1_buff, &c); //strcat it to char buffer
    printf("Thread 1 file input: %s\n", o1_buff);
    fclose(output);
  }
}

//Function for process 2 (Every 30 seconds)
void thread2_func(void) {
  char *number;
  while(1) {
    usleep(50000);
    //Reading from file
    output = fopen("output2.txt", "r");
    fscanf(output, "%c", &number);
    strcat(o2_buff, &number);
    printf("Thread 2 file input: %s\n", o2_buff);
    fclose(output);
  }
}

//Function for process 3 (Every 120 seconds)
void thread3_func(void) {
  char *character;
  while(1) {
    usleep(50000);
    //Reading from file
    output = fopen("output3.txt", "r");
    fscanf(output, "%c", &character);
    strcpy(o3_buff, &character);
    printf("Thread 3 file input: %s\n", o3_buff);
    fclose(output);
  }
 }
```

However, when running my program I get the following error message[image]

What exactly is the issue here? If the issue is the fact that my buffers are getting full (which I created by "char o1_buff[1024] = {'\0'}" and so on) then I have a separate function which I plan to implement a mutex in once the buffers output is written to an output file.

Comment: You talk about processes and threads — don't mix the two up.  If you're working with POSIX threads, your thread functions all have the incorrect signature; they should be `void *thread1_func(void *unused) { … }` and should finish with `return NULL;`, though it's a bit moot since they all have infinite loops in them at the moment.  Your claims of 1, 30, and 120 second intervals are not justified by the code you've shown.

Comment: You seem to have a single global variable `FILE *output` that the threads carelessly overwrite on a whim.  That bodes ill.  In `thread1_func()`, you have `char *c;` instead of `char c;` — ouch!  Similar complaints in the other two functions.  You've not shown the `o1_buff` etc global variable definitions.  It isn't clear whether the main thread will be accessing those; if so, you've got concurrency control problems.

Comment: Please reread about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) and remember to create an MCVE when you ask a question like this.  Since there is no `free()` call in this code, it isn't possible to begin to guess where the problem is occurring.  It looks like you're on a Mac, or perhaps a BSD machine.

Comment: The issue was the fact that I was only using one output file pointer for the 3 files. When I split it up it fixed my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

<sup>*Transferring comments into an answer.*</sup>

You talk about processes and threads — don't mix the two up.

If you're working with POSIX threads, your thread functions all have the incorrect signature; they should be similar to `void *thread1_func(void *unused) { … }` and should finish with `return NULL;`, though it's a bit moot since they all have infinite loops in them at the moment.

Your claims of 1, 30, and 120 second intervals are not justified by the code you've shown.

- You seem to have a single global variable `FILE *output` that the threads carelessly overwrite on a whim. That bodes ill.
- In `thread1_func()`, you have an uninitialized pointer `char *c;` instead of `char c;` — ouch! Similar complaints in the other two functions.

You've not shown the `o1_buff` etc global variable definitions. It isn't clear whether the main thread will be accessing those; if so, you've got concurrency control problems.

Please reread about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and remember to create an MCVE when you ask a question like this.

Since there is no `free()` call in this code, it isn't possible to begin to guess where the problem is occurring. It looks like you're on a Mac, or perhaps a BSD machine, given the message from the crash.

> The issue was the fact that I was only using one output file pointer for the 3 files. When I split it up it fixed my issue.

Be cautious with global variables — especially shared ones — in thread programming.  While the POSIX I/O streams protect open file handles from interference between threads (see [`flockfile()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/flockfile.html) for more information), it doesn't protect them from abuse like different `fopen()` calls in different threads causing the variable to be reset without regard to which thread is using it.

The simplest fix would be to make the variable local to the thread functions; then there's no interference.  Alternatively, create three global variables. Or alternatively again, use a mutex or similar access control mechanism to prevent the threads from interfering with each other while using the global variable.  In this context (and many others), making the variable local is preferable to the alternatives.

Comment: I was wondering about the same issue with the char *c. When I made it with just a char c strcat was complaining to me that the second arg was not a pointer char* to which I attempted to make char c[] with that not working as well. If I keep it as char c and then try to do &c in the strcat call I get values susch as 40? 60? etc etc, if I dont ask for the address in strcat and use just c I get a seg fault. Also the intervals for my functions are specified in three different programs that were given by my prof with sleeps in them for the 1, 30, 120 sec. Also in my pthread_create i use void castin

Comment: I just reread the last bit about the file global variable issue. Thinking about it, it makes a lot of-sense. Thanks for the tip.